# Getting date in java on Centos OS is not correct?

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, centos

Greetings all
i have a j2ee app using spring framework
and while debugging on the online server (centos os)
when trying to get the date in the app by printing the value of `new Date();` object
it retrieves the time in GMT-6 although when getting the server time through the terminal
command date it's retrieved in GMT time, the real time, so i am wondering where does the GMT-6 came from, why such strange behaver occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after restarting the apache,tomcat... but still don't know why such behaviour occurs.

Comment: Check to make sure no code in the application changes the default JVM-wide Timezone.

Comment: can you please tell me what methods you think may do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a locale issue to me. More specifically, it's not an issue, it's just Java's way of handling different timezone/regional settings.

Using code from [this article](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/print-all-java-system-properties):

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
  String value = (String)p.get(key);
  System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

you can see how Java interprets your environment.

If you change CentOS' timezone/regional settings, Java should pick up that change and display time accordingly.

But that sounds like an overkill and [customizing date format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) based on locale might be what you need.

Different applications may output the same date differently.

Comment: please see my above answer, and tell me what do you think ?

Comment: @sword101: is the outputted GMT-6 time correct? Does it happen once again upon restarting? If yes, when? What's your debugger?

Comment: yes the time is correct in GMT-6, and yes it happens again after restarting, but i didn't notice a pattern here, and i am debugging with log4j...

Comment: @sword101: are you using [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)? If yes, what's your date conversion specifier and date format specifier? Check your log4j.properties or log4j.xml file.

Comment: and if i use a simple sysout statement, the result is the same like the debugger, i don't think that the problem is related to the debugger, what do you think ?

Comment: @sword101: sounds like what I said earlier. Check [this link](http://miroirs.cesars.org/man/pages/CentOS-5.4/man1/date.1.txt). What do you have in `/etc/localtime`? What timezone does Java detect?

Comment: in /etc/localtime the time zone is GMT0, and what do you mean by the timezone that java detect, coz as i said eariler at the end of the date object there's the timezone GMT-6

Comment: @sword101: what are values of `user.country`, `user.timezone`, `user.language`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhere in your application the default timezone is changed with `TimeZone.setDefault(..)` ?

Comment: searched the whole app, didn't find such a thing setting the timezone to the default.